# Get reason for failed LWP::Simple head request

Tags: perl, lwp

I have migrated my scrilpts from CentOS 7 to 8 and there's a new Perl version. I have the folowing snippet that uses `head` to check if a URL exists:

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $sitemapurl = "https://www.prosinger.net";
if (head($sitemapurl)) {
    ...
}
else {
    print "The $sitemapurl doesn't exist\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

It now always returns that the URL doesn't exist. I'm quite sure that this has to do something with https (I have perl-LWP-Protocol-https installed), but I'm not sure how to get any feedback information from head method to check what the error code is.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) instead of `LWP::Simple`, which allows you to get an error message:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $sitemapurl = "https://www.prosinger.net";
my $req = $ua->head($sitemapurl);
if ($req->is_success) {
    ...
} else {
    die "Could not head($sitemapurl): " . $req->status_line;
}
```

Running this code prints:

> Could not head(https://www.prosinger.net): 403 Forbidden at head.pl line 15.

You can fix this (for this specific website; this will not work for all website) by setting a User-Agent in your `LWP::UserAgent` object:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( agent => 'anything seems to work' );
```

Of interest is the [`decoded_content`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response#$r-%3Edecoded_content(-%options-)) method of `HTTP::Response` that allows you to get the content of the request (you don't need it in that case, but you might later):

```
my $req = $ua->get(...);
if ($req->is_success) {
    my $content = $req->decoded_content;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I didn't consider changing the code so far.
My doubt is, that this exact same code is working on an old system installation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation of [`head`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple#head) says that it returns undef if the request fails (and I've checked the [code](https://metacpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/source/lib/LWP/Simple.pm#L55), that's indeed what it returns), and using `get` won't work as it also returns `undef` (cf its [code](https://metacpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/source/lib/LWP/Simple.pm#L36)) if the request fails, and the documentation says "You will not be able to examine the response code or response headers". I'm afraid that `LWP::Simple` is, as its name suggests, simple...

Answer (score 0):

Your code that uses LWP::Simple and Dada's version that switches to LWP::UserAgent are basically doing the same thing, except that you can get details of the error when using LWP::UserAgent.

Running the LWP::UserAgent version gives this error:

> Could not head(https://www.prosinger.net): 500 Can't connect to [www.prosinger.net:443](http://www.prosinger.net:443) (SSL connect attempt failed error:2707307E:OCSP routines:OCSP_check_validity:status not yet valid)

And Googling that error message gives [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299380/unable-to-make-ssl-connecting-with-vimeo-api-url) as the first result. Is it possible that the clocks on your your client machine and the server are out of sync?